# Excel: How do I create a cell that depends on a dropdown list selected item?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to create simple user interface in Excel 2003:

User selects a customer in drop down list and customer adress cell should be populated.

I have created list of customers on a special workbook spreadsheet as a table like:

```
   1           2
======================= 
1 Customer1   Address1
2 Customer2   Address2 
3 Customer3   Address3
```

I have selected "customers column" (Customer1, Customer2, Customer3) and created a named list "customers". Then I came back to my user spreadsheet and placed dropdown list that has values from "customers" named list.

User can select Customer1, Customer2 or Customer3 happily.

What shall I add to my workbook to populate address cell automatically when user chooses customer from a dropdown list ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create the "address book" with the complete list as in your sample, perhaps on the separate sheet (let's say `Sheet2` for example).

Then add in place of `Address1` (I think it's cell `B1`) the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),"Address not found!")
```

Here I assume your address book is located in columns A and B of Sheet2. This will include error check for missing addresses as well.

Comment: @SiddharthRout at your service!)

Answer (score 3):

You should make a seperate table with all your customer names and addresses. Then use vlookup to look up the address for the inputted customer name in your interface:

[image: Example1]

Answer (score 2):

This is simple - In the filed you want to be populated with the address, just use a simple `Vlookup` function based upon this table.